# Was this not sufficiently explained enough to deserved a down vote?

Tags: discussion, downvotes, specific-answer, answer-quality

I answered a question by a new user which was a relatively simple answer on a simple question.

This question is just an example; it was what got me thinking "At what point does the explanation stop on simple questions that require a simple answer?"

My answer was straightforward; a description of what functions were used, the code, and a SQL fiddle link.

I felt (and still do feel) this is sufficient, as did other voters who sat the answer at +5.

The question looked like this at +5

```
Using a combination of ROUND, EXP, SUM and LOG

SELECT ROUND(EXP(SUM(LOG([Col A]))),1)
FROM yourtable
SQL FIDDLE: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d43c8/2/0
```

After which I got a comment saying "can you please explain your code a bit?".
Not a problem, and I replied "@Alex Sure, what don't you feel is clearly explained?" which may have been their trigger if they took it the wrong way and gave a down vote.

Now I went on to break down my answer in detail.

But was (is) this kind of explanation necessary on this question?

[How to Multiply all values within a column with SQL like SUM()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30665719/how-to-multiply-column-with-sql-like-sum)

Comment: How can you possibly know who, and for what reason a downvote was given?

Comment: I don't think calling out the commentor in your answer is constructive. Why not just explain it without the implied "Huh, huh, for the one idiot who didn't get it, huh huh".

Comment: I dont, didnt specifically say it was the comment-er, i said it may have been

Comment: @TZHX fair enough (removed them)

Comment: You've opened this Meta question for a single downvote, on *an answer with five upvotes*?!

Comment: @jonrsharpe not just this question, this was just what got me thinking. was more of a at what point does the explanation stop on simple questions that require a simple answer

Comment: @Matt It's entirely up to the judgement of each voter to determine how much explanation is necessary for any given post.  There is no (and really can be no) objective standard.

Comment: Where are Tim's keys?

Comment: Surely the simplest solution is that we all club together and buy Tim several sets of spare keys. We could start a Kickstarter campaign to get Tim extra keys. Problem solved.

Comment: @RobertLongson i dont understand that reference!

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/215397

Answer (score 3):

Since you seem to be asking about why your explanation was not sufficient, there was not an explanation that I could see.

Your original answer was:

> Using a combination of `ROUND`, `EXP`, `SUM` and `LOG`
>
> ```
> SELECT ROUND(EXP(SUM(LOG([Col A]))),1)
> FROM yourtable
> ```
>
> SQL FIDDLE: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d43c8/2/0

The beginning just says what's in the code, and the end gives a way to test it. There is nothing in the answer to explain *why* or *how* the code works.

Your new answer is much better, but it could be further improved by explaining how these operations work together since they may not appear related to some.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your more general question, in general, unexplained answers are not as useful as answers that explain why they work.

There is a common proverb:

> Give a man a fish, and you feed him for a day. Teach a man to fish and you feed him for a life time.

Without explaining what your code does, at least to some extent, it is useful to people who just want to copy-and-paste their work from the Internet. It is just doing their job for them. The next time these people have a problem, they will again look to Stack Overflow to solve it for them.

If you explain your answer -- these people will *still* just copy your code. But for those who *want to learn how to do their own job*, they will be able to. You add to their knowledge, rather than just temporarily inhabiting the clipboard of their computer.

<sub>Whether that was the motivation for the down-vote on your linked answer, only the person who gave that vote can know (unless they volunteer that information, and you trust them).</sub>

Comment: confucius... that fits amazingly